# Insert multiple rows conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I need to insert multiple (hundreds) rows in a table and I don't want to insert each row by hand. There has to be a way to do this, right?

The table looks like this: (SQL Server)

| id | userFK | appUserFK | dateA | createdBy | dateB | changedBy | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 2023-7-28 | Dan | 2023-7-28 | Dan | NULL |
| 2 | 4 | 7 | 2023-7-28 | Dan | 2023-7-28 | Dan | NULL |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 2023-7-28 | Dan | 2023-7-28 | Dan | NULL |
| 3 | 9 | 12 | 2023-7-28 | Dan | 2023-7-28 | Dan | NULL |

Now I want to add as many rows as `appUserFK = 7` has. For every entry that has `appUserFK = 7`, I want to add another entry with the same `userFK` but `appUserFK = 16` and also `19`. So that every row where a `userFK` has a corresponding `appUserFK of 7`, also has a row with the `appUserFK of 16 and 19`.
My single Insert-Query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [myTable].[dbo].[user] (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, changedBy)
VALUES (3, 16, GETDATE(), 'Josh', GETDATE(), 'Josh');

INSERT INTO [myTable].[dbo].[user] (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, changedBy)
VALUES (4, 16, GETDATE(), 'Josh', GETDATE(), 'Josh');

INSERT INTO [myTable].[dbo].[user] (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, changedBy)
VALUES (5, 16, GETDATE(), 'Josh', GETDATE(), 'Josh');
```

And so on...

Thanks in advance!

I tried this query but it does not work:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, changedBy) 
SELECT userFK, 16, GETDATE(), 'Josh', GETDATE(), 'Josh' FROM myTable WHERE appUserFK = 7 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT userFK FROM myTable WHERE appUserFK = 16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of INSERT and SELECT to achieve what you want.
I have an example for you:

```
INSERT INTO Customers_Backup (CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName,     Country)
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName, Country 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico'
```

This query inserts all rows from the customers table into customers_backup which have the country 'Mexico'. Instead of copying all data you can just use hardcoded data as well. Let me know if you need further assistance or if this hint is enough for you to work on your exact problem.

Comment: Would this work? `INSERT INTO myTable (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, changedBy)
SELECT userFK, 16, GETDATE(), 'Josh', GETDATE(), 'Josh' FROM myTable WHERE appUserFK = 7;`? And if so, how can I skip already **already existing** relations/ entries? Thanks.

Comment: Yes i think this would work well. If you want to skip existing data just extend your WHERE clause with an NOT EXISTS (subquery). EXISTS returns true if there is at least 1 row returned from the sub query.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. :( But I think I understood the concept now and can figure it out. Thanks again. :)

Comment: If not just add the whole DB schema aswell as some test data and your SQL to your question so I can have a better look and reproduce the problem myself

Answer (score 1):

You can use The SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement:

```
insert into [user](userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, dateB, changedBy)
select userFK, 16, GETDATE(), createdBy, GETDATE(), changedBy
from [user]
where appUserFK = 7
union all
select userFK, 19, GETDATE(), createdBy, GETDATE(), changedBy
from [user]
where appUserFK = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can INSERT based on a SELECT query rather than individually. This would work even if more records were added where appUserFK is 7. The UNION ALL part combines the two SELECTs so they can be INSERTed together.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DateNow AS date

SET @DateNow = GETDATE() -- to save repeatedly fetching the date

INSERT INTO [user] (userFK, appUserFK, dateA, createdBy, dateB, changedBy)
  SELECT 
    userFK, 
    16, 
    @DateNow, 
    'Josh', 
    @DateNow,
    'Josh'
  FROM
    [user]
  WHERE
    appUserFK = 7
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    userFK, 
    19, 
    @DateNow, 
    'Josh', 
    @DateNow,
    'Josh'
  FROM
    [user]
  WHERE
    appUserFK = 7
```

Comment: You could try declaring the updating user as a variable too, the user id to copy to and the user id to copy from. This would allow you to re-use the SQL statement for similar situations in the future. That's if you anticipate needing to do this regularly.